# Devise + CanCan: Defined CRUD like told in Tut, now how to restrict usage of controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i created a Devise with CanCan integration like told on:
http://starqle.com/articles/rails-3-authentication-and-authorization-with-devise-and-cancan-part-1/
http://starqle.com/articles/rails-3-authentication-and-authorization-with-devise-and-cancan-part-2/

now i have two resources for my User class. Devise and a RESTful resources :users.
as mentioned in the tutorial, i included in the RESTful edit_user_path a form for editing the rights for the user.
now i don't understand how i can restrict normal users to access that edit function and use devise edit function for that.

Is it possible to just restrict a user to

```
can :manage, User
```

but he still can manage devise controller?

**Solved**

Just can add an in ability.rb

```
can :assign_roles, User
```

and then in _form for RESTful edit

```
<% if can? :assign_roles, current_user %>
```

and then let Users edit either over RESTful _form or Devise form, doesn't matter then

**Edit**

_form.html.erb (or haml)

```
<% if can? :assign_roles, @user %>
```

may work too. depends on your controller. should work better since i have made a bit workaround to fit it to current_user

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure that your abilities get checked also on controller level, you should add `load_and_authorize_resource` to it.

```
class ProductsController < ActionController::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource
end
```

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/authorizing-controller-actions

if you just show / hide the links in the view depending on the `<% if can? %>` method, a user might still type the direct link to e.g. edit action in the adress bar